# How would I redirect requests for one page to another is IIS?

Tags: iis, redirect

How would I redirect requests to a URL like

```
http://www.mydomain.com/foo.aspx
```

to another URL like

```
http://www.mydomain.com/bar.aspx
```

in IIS.

Can this be done in IIS 6.0 or 7.0?

Comment: redirect or forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an existing foo.aspx file then you can set a Location header to redirect to the new file/URL:

```
<script runat="server">
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
Response.AddHeader("Location","bar.aspx");
}
</script>
```

In IIS6, if the file exists, using the management snap-in, you can right-click to open the properties for the file and select to redirect to another location.

In IIS7, you can use the [Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) to capture the request and redirect it.

Comment: For IIS6 it's described here in detail http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937691

Answer (score 1):

You can use [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) in IIS7.0.